# Vim: How to append even lines to odd lines

Tags: vim, text-editors, newlines

I have the following lines.

```
1
4
2
10
3
20
4
35
5
56
...
...(many more lines after this)
```

And I want to change to the following in Vim.

```
1 4
2 10
3 20
4 35
5 56
...
...
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please, don't just use this site to get easy answers without much effort. Show us what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nice thing about `:global` is that it handles added and removed lines very well. So, we can use it to apply the `:join` command to all lines:

```
:global/^/join
```

An alternative would be a *recursive macro*.

Answer (score 7):

Another option would be

```
:%norm J
```

where you apply the join command to the entire buffer

**Breakdown**

```
:         enters command-line mode
%         Applies to the entire buffer
norm      execute following commands in normal mode
J         Join line
```